# How to use a shape drawable for actionbar shadow (no intrinsic height?)

Tags: android

I want to supply my own drawbable for my ActionBar. I know you can do it via:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@drawable/my_drawable</item>
</style>
```

but I want to use a shape drawable, which doesn't have an intrinsic width or height. I tried  specifying the width/height:

```
// my_drawable
<shape 
  android:shape="rectangle"
  android:height="10dp"
  android:width="100dp">
  <solid android:color="#ffff0000" />
</shape>
```

but nothing gets rendered. If I swap in a 9 patch png, it shows up ok. Even if this does work, I would also need the width to not be an explicit integer, rather something like "fill_parent".

Thanks

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html search for shape drawable

Comment: @pskink I see a width and height attribute, but the type is supposed to be of "integer" - so how would I specify width = fill?

Comment: you said you want it to be 50dp tall, didn't you?

Comment: @pskink yeah I forgot to mention I want it to fill width just like a nine-patch.

Comment: and now it doesn't fill? did you try that?

Comment: Yeah nothing is shown actually, even if I give it an explicit width. Will update question to show.

Comment: how do you use my_drawable?

Comment: I updated the question to show how I use it with the actionbar.

Comment: sorry I know nothing about windowContentOverlay, as far I know you need to define an item with name android:actionBarStyle and pointing to the style extending android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar